# Oracle query all_tab_columns.data_default (type LONG)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have run this query:

```
SELECT
    OWNER,
    TABLE_NAME,
    COLUMN_NAME,
    DATA_TYPE,
    DATA_LENGTH,
    (CASE
        WHEN DATA_PRECISION IS NULL THEN 0
        ELSE DATA_PRECISION
     END) DATA_PRECISION,
    (CASE
        WHEN DATA_SCALE IS NULL THEN 0
        ELSE DATA_SCALE
     END) DATA_SCALE,
    NULLABLE,
    COLUMN_ID
    DEFAULT_LENGTH,
    DATA_DEFAULT,
    (CASE
        WHEN DATA_DEFAULT IS NULL THEN '0'
        ELSE DATA_DEFAULT
     END) DATA_DEFAULT1
FROM 
    all_tab_columns
WHERE 
    table_name LIKE 'TABLE1';
```

But it throws an error at column `DATA_DEFAULT`:

> ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got LONG
>   00932. 00000 - "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"

How can I fix that?

Thanks!

Comment: What are the types for `DATA_PRECISION`, `DATA_SCALE`, and `DATA_DEFAULT` ?

Comment: The problem most likely lies in one or more of your `CASE` expressions.

Comment: You forget `,` after `COLUMN_ID`.

Comment: Here is explanation for all columns type: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2094.htm

Comment: I have put , after COLUMN_ID  but problem is with DATA_DEFAULT with type LONG.

Comment: Hi Catalin, instead of complicating the logic here, you can just replace this in your case statement `(CASE
    WHEN DATA_DEFAULT IS NULL THEN 0
  END) DATA_DEFAULT1` - this will work and will give you 0 (as number), in case the data_default is null. For the rest of the cases, you can use the already selected DATA_DEFAULT field. Does that sound ok for this implementation and use case ?

Comment: Yes, this is implementation but didn't work: (CASE WHEN DATA_DEFAULT IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE TO_CHAR(DATA_DEFAULT) END) DATA_DEFAULT1

Comment: It doesn't work, because you put the ELSE clause back ... just trim it and expect nothing returned by data_default1, in case there's value.

Comment: Ok I understand but I need else value.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't do anything with a `LONG`. It's a PITA that Oracle still use them in the data dictionary.

You can use XML:

```
select owner
     , table_name
     , column_name
     , data_type
     , data_length
     , case
           when data_precision is null then 0
           else data_precision
       end data_precision
     , case
           when data_scale is null then 0
           else data_scale
       end data_scale
     , nullable
     , column_id
     , default_length
     , case
           when default_length is null then '0'
           else
               extractvalue
               ( dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype
                 ( 'select data_default from user_tab_columns where table_name = ''' || c.table_name || ''' and column_name = ''' || c.column_name || '''' )
               , '//text()' )
       end as data_default
from   all_tab_columns c
where  table_name like 'TABLE1';
```

From 12.1 you can write your own lookup function inline:

```
with
     function get_default(tab varchar2, col varchar2) return varchar2
     as
         dflt varchar2(4000);
     begin
         select c.data_default into dflt
         from   user_tab_columns c
         where  c.table_name = upper(tab)
         and    c.column_name = upper(col);
         
         return dflt;
     end get_default;
select owner
     , table_name
     , column_name
     , data_type
     , data_length
     , case
           when data_precision is null then 0
           else data_precision
       end data_precision
     , case
           when data_scale is null then 0
           else data_scale
       end data_scale
     , nullable
     , column_id
     , default_length
     , get_default(c.table_name, c.column_name) as data_default
from   all_tab_columns c
where  table_name like 'TABLE1%'
/
```

Or of course make a standalone function or package function that does the same thing.

Comment: Working very well!

Comment: I had to replace the internal line with `( 'select data_default from all_tab_columns where table_name = ''' || c.table_name || '''  and owner = ''' || c.owner || ''' and column_name = ''' || c.column_name || ''''  )` for it to work.

Comment: @MikhailOrlov no, you didn't have to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code how to print your LONG.  You can change it as you wish.

```
set serveroutput on
declare
  cursor c1 is
  select 
  OWNER
    ,TABLE_NAME
    ,COLUMN_NAME
    ,DATA_TYPE
    ,DATA_LENGTH
    ,(CASE WHEN DATA_PRECISION IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE DATA_PRECISION END) DATA_PRECISION
    ,(CASE WHEN DATA_SCALE IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE DATA_SCALE END) DATA_SCALE
    ,NULLABLE
    ,COLUMN_ID
    ,DEFAULT_LENGTH
    ,DATA_DEFAULT
  from all_Tab_columns where table_name='ENTITIES' and default_length is not null;
v_long long;
v_varchar2 varchar2(4000);
begin
  for loop1 in c1
  loop
    v_long := loop1.DATA_DEFAULT;
    v_varchar2 := substr(v_long,1,4000);
    dbms_output.put_line(v_varchar2); 
  end loop;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need a simple query without cursor.

Comment: I would also like to know how to show LONG without cursor.

Comment: @sandman - Change this answer to a function definition and incorporate its usage in the query above. Then it might look like an answer, as now you're just suggesting a way to show long values.

Comment: @g00dy I was suggesting exactly that, as his problem was with the long and showing default values.  I'm sure poster can do as you suggested :)

Comment: @sandman, I agree, but since this function should be used in a query, which might get into a view and possibly a table to be created, then this function should return a value. You would suggest what type of value should it return etc. and how to use it properly. I'm just saying here ... this is just in case you get a downvote and wonder why is it so .. (not getting it from me though)

Comment: @g00dy Your advice is appreciated and well received.  Will do if poster wants it, but stated he wants a simple query.  Catalin?

Answer (score 0):

William's answer was helpful, but didn't work for me since my `DEFAULT_DATA` column included some illegal characters.

Here's another SQL only solution that accounts for illegal characters by using the DBMS_XMLGEN.CONVERT function:

```
SELECT table_name, column_name, data_default
  FROM XMLTABLE(
           '/ROWSET/ROW'
           PASSING xmltype(
                       REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(
                               DBMS_XMLGEN.CONVERT(DBMS_XMLGEN.getxml(
                               'SELECT table_name, column_name, data_default
                                  FROM user_tab_columns')),
                         '&lt;([A-Z0-9_\/]+)&gt;',
                                '<\1>'),
                         '&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot;?&gt;',
                                '<?xml version="1.0"?>'))
           COLUMNS table_name   VARCHAR2(128 BYTE)  PATH 'TABLE_NAME',
                   column_name  VARCHAR2(128 BYTE)  PATH 'COLUMN_NAME',
                   data_default VARCHAR2(4000)      PATH 'DATA_DEFAULT');
```